# Can you get separate workspaces in separate screens?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I am running ubuntu 19.04 with 2 monitors.
Right now, my options to switch workspaces are to either switch workspaces in the primary display while the other one doesn't change, or switch both of them at once.

I would love to have the option to also switch workspaces in the secondary while keeping primary static, or change each of them to arbitrary spaces and get any configuration.

Is there any way to get gnome to do this? Is there any other desktop environment with a feature like the one I described?

Comment: How about the [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) Gnome Shell extension?

Comment: @user3140225 I installed and looked it around a bit, if it allows to independently switch workspaces I don't know how. It just makes both monitors switch in parallel

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't allow you to change workspaces independently. It only provides independent overview for the second monitor.